# Inserting large amount of data in Apache Ignite

Tags: c#, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite .NET thin client `2.8.1` to insert a large amount of data in the Apache Ignite node. Ignite is hosted on Amazon Linux AMI.
I am trying to insert over `500000` records using PutAllAsync method:

```
await cacheClient.PutAllAsync(entities); // ICacheClient<int, T>
```

After that I see the following exception in client logs:

```
2021-02-03 07:23:37.9917 - NO_TRACE - ****************** - Error: Could not get data from cache
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException System.Object InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean) System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.SocketRead(Byte[] buf, Int32 pos, Int32 len)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.ReceiveBytes(Int32 size)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.ReceiveMessage()
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.SendRequest(RequestMessage& reqMsg)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc, Func`3 errorFunc)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.DoOutInOp[T](ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction, Func`2 readFunc)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.Cache.CacheClient`2.DoOutOp(ClientOp opId, Action`1 writeAction)
```

And the following error in ignite logs:

```
[07:44:53,529][WARNING][grid-timeout-worker-#22][ClientListenerNioListener] Unable to perform handshake within timeout [timeout=10000, remoteAddr=/172.31.56.14:52631]
```

Are there any best practices of how to insert over 5000 records in ignite cache? Insert batches within transaction?

Comment: Doesn't Apache Ignite have a streaming mode?

Comment: Check the [data streaming docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-streaming) and the C# example

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is no streaming in the Thin Client yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ignite is hosted on Amazon Linux AMI

Where do you run the thin client? I suspect that the issue can be simply the low connection speed between the server and the client.

- Can you test the connection speed?
- What is the size of the data, in megabytes?
- How much time does PutAll take for 10, 100, 1000 entries?

There is no `DataStreamer` in the thin client (yet), so my suggestions are:

- Split one big `PutAll` into multiple smaller ones (e.g. 100 entries at a time)
- Increase timeouts on [server](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ClientConnectorConfiguration.html) and [client](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.IgniteClientConfiguration.html#Apache_Ignite_Core_Client_IgniteClientConfiguration_SocketTimeout)

---

**UPDATE:** `DataStreamer` is now available in Ignite.NET thin client:

- [IIgniteClient.GetDataStreamer](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.IIgniteClient.html#Apache_Ignite_Core_Client_IIgniteClient_GetDataStreamer__2_System_String_)
- https://ptupitsyn.github.io/Whats-New-In-Ignite-Net-2.11/

Comment: Tnank you, increasing client timeout fixed the issue. Will try to implement batches insertion later.

Comment: can you share which timeouts settings resolved your issue?

Comment: @Pavel - Which timeout parameters to be changed? for e.g. Idle or Handshake at the server side  , or Sockettimeout in client side.

Comment: @JustinMathew `SocketTimeout` on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you actually need to use some sort of streaming mode.
- If you have persistence, consider disabling WAL beforehand.
- Maybe you have hit some specific issue such as [IGNITE-14076](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-14076). Try if you can work around it by using smaller batches.
- Try adjusting timeouts for thin client in ClientConnectorConfiguration and client configuration.